# Is there a way for WebStorm to set different font sizes for different file types?

Tags: webstorm, editing

I am using WebStorm for both programming and blogging (I am using a static site generator).

I have set my font size to be small so that I can have a larger overview of the code file while programming.

However, when I write post for my blog, I prefer the font to be bigger to be easier on the eyes.

Is there a way to do this in WebStorm?

Comment: What an amazing idea!

Comment: No. But you can change font size manually by zooming in or out when needed (either `Ctrl+Mouse Wheel` or some keyboard shortcut; the mouse one may need to be enabled first in settings).

Answer (score 1):

Not currently possible, please vote for [IDEA-146471](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-146471) to be notified on any progress with his feature.
But you can zoom the font in current editor tab. To zoom text using keyboard, you need to assign preferred shortcuts to **Increase font size**, **Decrease font size** and **Reset font size** actions in **Preferences | Keymap | Editor Actions**; to do the same using mouse, enable **Change font size (Zoom) with Ctrl+Mouse Wheel** option in **Preferences | Editor | General** and use `Ctrl+mouse wheel` to zoom

Comment: Appreciate the tip Lena